# How to connect stdin of a list of commands (with pipes) to one of those commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, networking, netcat

I need to give the user ability to send/receive messages over the network (using `netcat`) while the connection is stablished (the user, in this case, is using `nc` as **client**). The problem is that I need to send a line **before** user starts interacting. My first attempt was:

```
echo 'my first line' | nc server port
```

The problem with this approach is that `nc` *closes* the connection when `echo` finishes its execution, so the user can't send commands via stdin because the shell is given back to him (and also the answer from server is not received because it delays some seconds to start answering and, as `nc` closes the connection, the answer is never received by the user).

I also tried grouping commands:

```
{ echo 'my first line'; cat -; } | nc server port
```

It works almost the way I need, but if server closes the connection, it will wait until I press `<ENTER>` to give me the shell again. I need to get the shell back when the server closes the connection (in this case, the client - my `nc` command - will **never** closes the connection, except if I press Ctrl+C).

I also tried named pipes, without success.

Do you have any tip on how to do it?

> Note: I'm using openbsd-netcat.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [`expect(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/).

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using expect? Do you have any tips using expect for my problem?

Comment: What's wrong with using `expect`?  Just write up a script that has `interact` in it in the right spots and it should be just fine.

Comment: I don't want to use non-standard tools (expect is not installed by default in Ubuntu, for example). But I'll read the manual and try, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is `cat` that wait for the 'enter'.
You may write a script execute after `nc` to kill the `cat` and it will return to shell automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `cat << EOF`, but I think it will not work as you expect.

I don't know how you can send `EOF` when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it works for you.

```
perl  -e "\$|=1;print \"my first line\\n\" ; while (<STDIN>) {print;}" | nc server port
```

Comment: Same problem as in solution `{ echo 'my first line'; cat -; } | nc server port
`

Comment: you sure? I tested and it works fine. I didn't spawn two processes like echo ... ; cat, it is one process.

Comment: the output from nc goes to the terminal, the output of perl goes to nc.

Answer (score 0):

This one should produce the behaviour you want:

```
echo "Here is your MOTD." | nc server port ; nc server port
```

Comment: It'll create two connections instead of just one and will create a problem to make software server-side work properly.

Comment: Run the server with -k and it will behave as you want.

Comment: It does not work because on server I'm executing `while [ 1 ]; do nc -kl 127.0.0.1 1234 < /tmp/pipe | ./my-script.sh > /tmp/pipe; echo connected; done` - client only receives stdout of `my-script.sh` once at two tries.